# VirtualBox networking issue

Tags: networking, virtualbox, ip

I have program that sends RTP packets. 
But I don't know what IP to access.

The IP address shown in VirtualBox is 10.0.2.2,
but I can't ping it from my operating system...

My computer is under work domain, and VirtualBox is on WORKGROUP.

I think this is the issue. Can someone please point me into the right direction on
how to configure this?

Comment: Wenfang Du: If you’re going to edit posts about VirtualBox, please ensure that it is capitalized correctly. And don’t call it “***the*** virtual box”.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In your VM settings -> Network. Change NAT to Bridged Adapter when your machine if turned Off:

This will update your IP to the main host (192.168.x.x probably)

[image]